# Why does svnversion call my working copy "modified" although it seems identical to the repository?

Tags: svn

Can anyone tell me why svn would indicate that a current working copy is modified, although all changes are checked in?

```
$ svn up
At revision 1520.
$ svn diff
$ svnversion 
1520M
```

Comment: What's the output of `svn status`?

Comment: @evil3: Thanks for this question. Actually it showed a directory with status "A", so I hadn't committed that yet. After committing it's all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this is your case, but for situations in which the project properties and settings are part of the project in the repository, it might happen that eventual changes to those properties (eventually automatically) on your end, might cause this difference.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I see this when the timestamp is modified. Although it can be a number of svn properties.

Assuming you haven't tagged or changed a property of the file such as svn:ignore I'd imagine the most likely senario is you've changed and reverted the change to the file locally.

Common cases where you may do this is adding in some debug code then removing again after debugging has finished.